# Preserve Object type when using moment.format()

Tags: javascript, momentjs, offset

I'm using moment library to convert a String to Date like this:

> var time = moment.parseZone("2021-09-28T12:00:00-07:00");

the result is: Tue Sep 28 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0700

But if I format this:

> var time = moment.parseZone("2021-09-28T12:00:00-07:00").format();

This convert 'time' to String so I can't manipulate it in my grid as a Date, how can I achieve this in order to sort my dates and display with a format?

note: if I use time.toDate(), it changes the offset to my local and need to preserve it.

Comment: You cannot set `Date` object's timezone (or offset). Therefore, you need to manipulate your sorting method of the grid library to sort by moment dates or another library's.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array of dates. You might have to flip your `diff` order to get the right sort order.

```js
// 'a' and 'b' are expected to be date objects
// Since your strings are full ISO 8601, you
// shouldn't require additional parsing
const array = stringArray.map(it => new Date(it));
const sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
  const mA = moment(a);
  const mB = moment(b);
  return mA.diff(mB) // or mB.diff(mA), depending on order
})
```